# Wikitude Altitude Issue

Tags: android, ios, gps, wikitude

I am gonna start using Wikitude SDK and have some doubts about its working...
I was wondering how the Wikitude's Architect Engine handles the Augmentation of POIs?
For example the Point of interest takes three values i.e latitude,longitude and altitude of the poi..which I assume is in meters above sea level. 
How does Wikitude handles the augmentation according to the altitude.
One scenario is I am holding the Phone when I am at ground...the augmentation in this case would be normal but what if I am at a top of building(around 300m above ground) will Wikitude handle the rise in altitude itself??(which I think it will not because there's no sensor on the phone to measure the height above ground except the gps value which is not that much accurate)
How can this scenario be achieved? Will the POIs need a different Altitude value?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess it can't be handled really well. Would require that both your and the POI's altitude are known pretty exactly. But GPS (especially near high buildings) and elevation maps are pretty inaccurate.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting...what else can be done?? Can I put the altitude in negative? This way if I am above 300m I can always minus the height of the building on which I am standing and put it static..

Comment: @PadmaKumar The issue is how to overcome this scenario so that the augmentation appears to be perfect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altitude is automatically taken into the calculation of the augmentation. There are a few things you should consider. Altitude information is only used when the accuracy of the GPS is high enough. This guarantees that the altitude will be reasonable accurate. However GPS altitude information has never the highest accuracy and you might see differences for POIs close to the user.

If you know the altitude more accurate then GPS, e.g. for predefined places you can use the injectLocation methods to set the altitude.